# How to use .pop() method of Stack in while loop in C#?

Tags: c#, stack

I can do this in JS or PHP:

```
while(var input = inputs.pop()) {
// do some bad things with input
}
```

I am trying same on C# and getting failed:

```
Stack<double[]> localInputs = new Stack<double[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
{
    localInputs.Push(inputs[i]);
}
while (input = localInputs.Pop()) // this cause error about converting double to bool
{
// do some bad things on c#
}
```

How I can do this? Why I can't do this? Assign should return boolean, nope?

Comment: You are pushing doubles onto the stack. Then popping out of the stack shall also return doubles, right? Hence the `InvalidCastException`, since the while loop awaits a boolean expression.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller actually he is pushing _arrays_ of `double` onto the stack.

Comment: _while(bool condition)_ this is the problem. Need to use Count to have the while satisfied.

Comment: @UweKeim: Absolutely! My bad. =) Besides, these are no boolean values. =) But I agree, I have read too rapidly. =)

Comment: You need to actually use a boolean condition, C# doesn't implicitly cast the double array to a boolean (like JS and PHP do). Besides, your strategy - even when correctly cast to a boolean - won't actually work. `Stack.Pop` throws an `InvalidOperationException` when the stack is empty, so you won't be able to handle that case by testing its return value. You *need* to test `Stack.Count` in order to safely pop from the stack.

Comment: You can do that in JS and PHP because those languages have type coercion (an evil, evil thing), a feature frequent in dynamically typed languages. Type coercion transforms a non-zero non-null value to `true`, and 0 or null to `false`, and that's why `while(input = stack.Pop())` compiles and runs. Thankfully, statically typed languages like C# and Java don't have any of that nonsense and force you to think about what you're writing. Welcome to the beautiful world of statically typed languages!

Comment: Note, however, that even in PHP or JS that code is **incorrect** - if the stack contains a value `0` or null, those values will be converted to false and you'd exit the loop, ignoring the remaining elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### "Assign should return boolean, nope?" & "Why can't I do this?"

Nope. The result of an assignment is the value that was assigned, not a Boolean (well, unless you're doing a Boolean assignement. But even then, it has nothing to do with whether the assignment succeeded or not). In other words, the value of the assignment: `var x = someStack.Pop()` is the object that is assigned to `x`. So the reason you can't do this is that there is no implicit conversion from the type you're assigning to a Boolean (and even if there was, it would not mean what you want it to mean).

For example:

```
var tmp = "Hello";
Console.WriteLine(tmp = "Goodbye"); // Write the output of an assignment to Console

// Note that the result of the assignment is 'Goodbye', not 'true'
```

Also, note that trying to `.Pop()` an empty stack will throw an `InvalidOperationException`, which is also not what you want for a `while` condition.

### "How can I do this?"

Instead, you need to use the `.Count` property to determine if there are any objects to pop, and then do the pop inside the while loop.

```
while (localInputs.Count > 0)
{
    var input = localInputs.Pop();
    // do some bad things on c#
}
```

Comment: @upvoters, I must be missing something, what does this post answer? (From Question: *this cause error about converting double to bool*)

Comment: @L.B The question asks "How to use .pop() method of Stack in while loop in C#?" and the answer provides the compiling code, I guess?!?

Comment: @UweKeim And I guess, OP's problem is quoted in my previous comment. Maybe people should read the whole question other than the title

Comment: @UweKeim "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime".

Comment: @Iridium Sorry, as a vegetarian I do not understand your metaphor.

Comment: @Iridium me too. what do you want to say? How is it related with the question?

Comment: @UweKeim not sure understanding the proverb requires one to actually eat fish, but the point is - just giving working code without explanation doesn't help the OP understand *why* he had the original issue, or how to avoid the same problem later. Of course this is all somewhat irrelevant given that explanation has now been added to the answer.

Comment: @iridium sorry, I forgot the smiles in my previous answer.

Comment: I really don't see how this answers the OP's comment `this cause error about converting double to bool` No one reads the codes in question anymore, only titles as L.B said?

Comment: @I4V Well, the OP had three questions: "How I can do this? Why I can't do this? Assign should return boolean, nope?" The first one is answered in the last code sample. The second and third (which are related) are answered in the first paragraph. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Unlike many other languages, C# does not perform implicitly conversions from numeric or reference types to `bool`, so `0` and `null` are not implicitly `false`. As such the conditions for `if`, `while` etc. must be actual Boolean expressions, which yours are not, hence the compile error.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in .net framework 4.8, you can use the [Stack<T>.TryPop(T) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1.trypop).

```cs
var localInputs = new Stack<double[]>();
foreach (var input in inputs)
    localInputs.Push(input);

while (localInputs.TryPop(out var input)) {
    // Have fun with input here
}
```